# how to use contains in web elements using java selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a string which has is like ABC £12,56 and I have another box "Cashbox" which should be 15% of this value which I have to assert. Now, when I am trying to find css of both these web elements "Cashbox", I can easily find for but for ABC £12,56 I am not able to get it only for the value , its the entire string which is getting selected.  Now I am thinking of using an if statement  with contains. This is just a sneak peak of what I am doing, there could be many mistakes in the following code. Appreciate if someone can help me learn and tell how to do it

[image]

Comment: Is there any `HTML` of the elements you can share?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is not check for `12,56`. It'd be better to pull the value from the element text, this way it'll also work for other values.

```
str_value = totalPrice.getText().split("£")[1];
float_value = parseFloat(str_value.replace, ",", ".");
```

float_value should now be `12.56` if the text of the element truly is `ABC $12,56`. If you do the same with `cashBox` you can then compare the 2 floats